# Return List of Interface in Java

Tags: java, list, interface

I have to create a word counter program. It is not very difficult logically but I am getting stuck with interfaces. So first I have to create an class which implements the defined interface:

```
public interface WordFrequency {
String getWord();
int getFrequency();
}
```

And I have to create another class which implements another interface as defined:

```
public interface WordFrequencyAnalyzer {
int calculateHighestFrequency(String text);
int calculateFrequencyForWord (String text, String word);
List<WordFrequency> calculateMostFrequentNWords (String text, int n);
}
```

Now, the third method in this interface returns a list of the previous interface. I will maintain the frequencies of words in a Map. This method requires me to return the words with N highest frequencies in the given text. It would be very easy to just sort the map with descending values and return accordingly, but how do I create a list of this particular interface with the correct values from the map to return in the required format?

Edit: I am using `Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>()` to store the words and their frequencies. This is what I need to store in `List<WordFrequency>` and return.

Comment: List<WordFrequency> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I did that, but how do I add elements to this list? the interface does not have data members in it. @ChengThao

Comment: The interface will be implemented by a subclass (as written in your question). When you implement an interface, you will inherit the _methods_ defined within the interface. From there, it's the subclass's job to keep track of data members.

Comment: @Rogue I thought so too, but the question states that the return type of the list would be List<WordFrequency> which is the interface. I created a list of this type but I am not able to add anything to it since it expects object of WordFrequency which can't be created? So how do I add elements to this list?

Comment: @redmelon7896 you need to provide an implementation of WordFrequency.  You could pass the information through the constructor, or through set methods.  You then create objects of this implementation and add to the list.

Comment: You can do `WordFrequency freq = new ConcreteWordFrequency(...);` just like you can do `List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();`. Being a subtype does not forgo being the interface you implement.

Comment: @Rogue why didn't I think of this lol. Would've been so straightforward like that. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider this example as a starting point for your use case:

**interface**

```
public interface WordFrequency {
    String getWord();
    int getFrequency();
}
```

**The implementation of above interface**

```
public class WordFreqImpl implements WordFrequency {

    final String w;
    final Integer f;

    public WordFreqImpl(String word, Integer freq) {
        w = word;
        f = freq;

    }
    @Override
    public String getWord() {
        return w;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFrequency() {
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" +
                "w=" + w +
                ", f=" + f;
    }
}
```

**demo of getting the list per your requirement**

```
public class WordFreqDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("k1",1);
        m.put("k2",2);
        m.put("k3",3);

        List<WordFrequency> wordFrequencyList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: m.entrySet()) {
            wordFrequencyList.add(new WordFreqImpl(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) {
            });
        }

        for (WordFrequency w: wordFrequencyList) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        
        // return wordFrequencyList as per use case
    }
}
```

**output**

```
w=k1, f=1
w=k2, f=2
w=k3, f=3
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. While you are on this journey of OOPS, check out `SOLID principles` that will help you structure your code better for long term maintainability

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual-articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you must have an concrete object that implements the interface. Then you can add that object to your list because it will now be a WordFrequency object in addition to whatever object it is by default. You will also need an object that implements the WordFrequencyAnalyzer interface as well.

The interface is a contract which guarantees that any object implementing the interface will have certain behaviors. It abstracts the implementation away and allows objects to be more polymorphic.

This is a good resources on interfaces

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Still an answer showing `record` as ad-hoc data class, and `Stream`-.

The `n` highest frequency entries from the map:

```
record Fr(String word, int frequency) implements WordFrequency {
    @Override
    public String getWord() {
       return word;
    }
    @Override
    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }
}

Map<String,Integer> m = ...
List<WordFrequency> wfs = m.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(e -> Comparator.comparingInt(e.getValue()).reversed()
                           .thenComparing(e.getKey()))
    .limit(n)
    .map(e -> new Fr(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()):
```